# Android Game Logic - Obsticles

Tags: java, android, android-studio, logic, game-physics

I have been working on android apps for a long time but now I have decided to create a game aside with my pre-calculus final. I have completed the whole code and it works perfectly except one tiny issue. First of the game is based on flying pig(my classmate's face) avoiding top and bottom osticle. I developed an algorithm so that the obsticles are evenly spaced and based on random selection placed either as the top or bottom of the screen **but never both at the same time!**. The algorithm that needs improvement is in the 3rd code segment!

**This is the screenshot of the problem: [screenshot here](http://www.filedropper.com/screenshot2015-05-30-00-07-45)
(My account is new so stackoverflow wont let me to share photos directly)**

This is the class that calls updates for all dynamic objects (ship = pig, bacon = bonus item, **BM = BarrierManager class's update() which updates the obsticles**)

//this will update the resources

```
void Update(float dt) {
    ship.update(dt);
    //bumbing
    if (!ship.death) {
        background.update(dt);
        **BM.update(dt);**


        for (int i = 0; i % 5 == 0; i++) {

            bacon.update(dt, BM.position);
        }
    }

    ArrayList<Point> bacon_point = new ArrayList<Point>(bacon.getArray());
    if (ship.bump(bacon_point.get(0), bacon_point.get(1), bacon_point.get(2), bacon_point.get(3))) {
        bacon.setX(-200);
        bacon.setY(-200);
        Message msg = BM.game_panel.game.handler.obtainMessage();
        msg.what = 0;
        BM.game_panel.game.handler.sendMessage(msg);

    }

    for (int i = 0; i < BM.TopWalls.size(); i++) {
        ArrayList<Point> temp = new ArrayList<Point>(BM.TopWalls.get(i).getArray());
        //after we have accest the TopWalls arraylist we can call bump that check TopWalls object's points position with the pig's points
        ArrayList<Point> temp2 = new ArrayList<Point>(BM.BottomWalls.get(i).getArray());
        //after we have accest the TopWalls arraylist we can call bump that check BottomWalls object's points position with the pig's points

        if ((ship.bump(temp.get(0), temp.get(1), temp.get(2), temp.get(3))) || (ship.bump(temp2.get(0), temp2.get(1), temp2.get(2), temp2.get(3))) || ship.death) {

            ship.death = true;
            game.onStop();
            while(f==0) {
                MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(game, R.raw.explosion_fart);
                mp.start();
                f++;
            }
            f++;
            Message msg = BM.game_panel.game.handler.obtainMessage();
            msg.what = 1;
            BM.game_panel.game.handler.sendMessage(msg);
            i = BM.TopWalls.size()-1;
            if(f == 8){
                thread.setRunning(false);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

In the BarrierManager I have created this update method which takes float dt = MainTheards general time for the game.
TopWalls is ArrayList this ArrayList is composed of top obsticles. Bottom walls is the same but BottomWalls.

//zreb decides if it should create TopWalls or BottomWalls object. This parameter is later transfered to the Barier.update method where I work with it

```
public void update(float dt){
        for (int i=0;i<Num+1; i++) {
            int zreb = new Random().nextInt(2);
            //{if} to make the spacing bigger
            if (i % 5 == 0){
                **TopWalls.get(i).update(dt, true, zreb);
                BottomWalls.get(i).update(dt, false, zreb);**
                if(zreb == 0){
                    position.set(TopWalls.get(i).getX(), TopWalls.get(i).getY());
                }
                else{
                    position.set(BottomWalls.get(i).getX(),BottomWalls.get(i).getY());
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Now this algoritm in the Barrier.class is where the magic went wrong. This update method takes the float dt mentioned earlier, a boolean variable for determining if the obsticle we work with at that instance is the Top or Bottom, and the zreb random int that determines if the top or bottom obsticle is going to be shown.

```
//problem! needs to be discussed
public void update(float dt, boolean b, int zreb) {

    //checking if the barrier is still there
    if (x<-bitmap.getWidth()){
        //'b'is passed from the Barriermanager - 'update' method, determining if we have to use monkey-true or farmer-false
        int raz = 200;
        int vyska = BM.dpos;
        //'zreb' helps me to randomly determine if monkey or ballard is going to appear

        //here it determines if we are going to have Top or Bottom obsticle in the game
        if(zreb == 1) {
            vyska = BM.dpos - raz;
        }
        else {
            vyska = BM.dpos + raz;
        }
        //koniec tohto trienedia

        if (b)
        {
            //setting the y value for the top wall
            y = vyska - BM.dl/2 - bitmap.getHeight()/2;
        }
        else{
            //setting the y value for bottom wall
            y = vyska + BM.dl/2 + bitmap.getHeight()/2;
        }
        //setting x-value
        x = (int) (x +bitmap.getWidth()*(BM.TopWalls.size()-1));
    }

    x = (int) (x - BM.game_panel.ShipSpeed*dt);
}
```

Do you have any idea why this "one-or-the-other" condition is not working properly?
This would help me lot because this error made me deactivate the app from the store.

Comment: I didn't get what exactly goes wrong. What line exactly is causing the problem? What do you expect from it, and what actually happens?

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose the 3rd code segment should give the x & y coordintes of obsticle that are created later in the draw(). There are 2 positions of the obsticles. A) Top one is visible B) Bottom one is visible. This code ought to not create both top and bottom barriers at the same x value. (then the flying pig would have no coridor to fly through - see "screeshot" link at the top of the problem). I figured this morning the code was executing perfectly problem was that the top and bottom obsticle had different width by 1 px causing the error in the "screenshot". I appreciate you tried to help.